# Add coordinate data to a Facebook Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now, as far as I know, the Facebook Graph API lets you add a location to an event as a string value.  Users are able to add location data to events manually though, by specifying a Facebook place or an address, and it looks like Facebook natively uses Bing maps to display the location.  Does anyone know if there are any plans to update the API to let developers add location data properly to events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API already supports location data.

Facebook will display the map correctly if you specify a location_id which could be the ID of a place page

Here is a code example...

```
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
        $event = array(
            'name' => stripslashes ($name),
            'description' => stripslashes ($description),
            'start_time' => $start_time,
            'end_time' => $end_time,
            'privacy_type' => $privacy,
            'location_id' => $location_id
        ); 
        $event[basename($flyer_file)] = '@' . realpath($flyer_file);

        try {
            $result = $facebook->api('me/events','post',$event);
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $error = "Facebook Error: $e";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - 'location_id' works, but for me, specifying the address parts has the result of Facebook recognizing and displaying a map, but it sits in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean (but labels it as San Jose).  Specifying 'latitude' and 'longitude' fails completely.  Are you sure this is working?  It's undocumented.

Comment: location_id definitely works and is documented, i don't think the others are supported though

Comment: My app uses this code and I have tested the three different cases separately and they all worked for me. Maybe the address that you entered wasn't recognized by the map?

Comment: Igy is right in that these features are undocumented. This functionality is pretty important to my app so I went back and tested it again. Specifying only Latitude/Longitude showed a map at the wrong place. Specifying only the address showed a map in the middle of the ocean, but was labeled with the correct city and state. Specifying the location_id worked as expected. A while ago I actually filed a bug report with Facebook to say that these fields were undocumented but functional (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194447123975181). Now they are no longer functional, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I edited the answer to only include location_id because of the issues mentioned above.

Comment: Just a side note - I tried lat/lon using both string and float values and both failed.